# How to delete invisible file?

Tags: files, disk-usage, delete, trash

I have a disk with 8 partitions, like this: 
[Disk partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ccwf.png)

And I wanted to delete a 23gb file. I dragged the folder to the trash, and the file disappeared, but later I checked the avail space with df -h and the 23gb were still there, but the folder is not visible. 
Later I was searching how to delete archives, and I discovered that dragging was not the form to do it.

Now I don't know how to delete the 23gb because I don't see it.
When I dragged the folder to the trash, this cursor appeared: [Cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pTnI.png)

Also, the 23gb folder was in /home and the trash in desktop… I don't know if this matters but just in case.
I asked in Xfce forums and they said that was a system issue, so that is why I ask here.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find Trash:

```
sudo updatedb
locate Trash
```

On my system, it's in a hidden directory `.local/share/Trash`.

Next, identify the file yoou want to remove:

```
ls ~/.local/share/Trash
```

You should see some directories; something like:

```
expunged  files  info
```

In my case, after looking a bit, a file I want to remove is in `files`.

```
ls ~/.local/share/Trash/files
some_file.avi
```

Now we remove it:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Trash/files/some_file.avi
```

Comment: When I wrote `locate Trash` I saw that the directory was `/home/.Trash-0/info/`
Should I replace the `.local` for `.Trash-0`?

Comment: I suggest that you list the contents of the directory `info` to see if your file is in there before you do anything permanent. The command `rm` for remove is very, very difficult to undo. `ls  /home/.Trash-0/info/ `

Answer (score 0):

Go to this directory:

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files
```

look for your file, if it exist there, delete it and it's permanently gone.

If you can't find it there then search to find it:

```
find /  -size +22G
```

If your search didn't bring you any result, run a file system check, there is a chance that your file has been removed while your filesystem doesn't know about it, based on your file system you can run something like:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sda2
```

*The partition should be unmounted.*

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably sitting in the trash can waiting to be emptied.  Right click on the trash icon and click Empty Trash and that should take care of it.

Really big files might not fit in the trash can.  Usually you are asked if you just want to delete it and if you respond yes, it's gone.

User trash is located in $HOME/.local/share/Trash
You can always go in there and manually remove stuff with the rm command if you like.

It's a bit more complicated but invoking Bleachbit (you may have to install it first) as a mortal user will clean up your $HOME file system.  It has a lot of options.  One of them is to scrub trash.

There are various maintenance processes that run from time to time.  If you wait a few hours the cleanup may take care of itself.